# JSF Serialization/Deserialization

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6, deserialization, cdi

We use JSF within our presentation layer. Most classes looks like this:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyHandler implements Serializable {
   @Inject
   private MyHelper helper;
   @EJB
   private transient MyFacade myFacade;

   ...
}
```

In general an JSF handler has one transient reference to an facade. The facade connects the presentation layer with our service layer. Helper classes will almost be injected through cdi.

JSF serializes the state of an handler but what happens on deserialization? Are the references automagically be restored? How could I check this or tell JSF to serialize/deserialize an managed jsf bean(testing)?

Answer (score 2):

[As per spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/injectionelresolution.html#clientproxies) all (relevant) CDI-managed dependencies are proxied and the proxies are required to be passivable, so there is no problem with de-/serialization :)

> [...] Finally, client proxies may be passivated [...]

Comment: Could your please expand on this answer a little? Does this mean that the proxies are serializable?